# Trying to create MySQL database gives HTTP/404 The requested URL alias not defined

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm having a small problem and am in need of a help from more experienced people.

I'm trying to create a MySQL database with PHP code, but I'm getting this message: "HTTP/404
The requested URL alias for C:/Apache24/htdocs/testsite_01/Error creating database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'testbase_db' is not defined."

I have Apache, PHP and MySQL installed on my home PC and Apache and MySQL are started and running. I have tried checking Apache's httpd.conf file, but I'm quite new to this server stuff and am not sure if it's something in there I should change, or add to make the problem disappear.

I use the default Apache htdocs folder for the files and have a sub folder there called testsite_01 for this particular file. However, that shouldn't be the problem, as it gives the same message when moving everything to the default root folder and trying to run from there. I have tried Googling and reading quite lot of stuff here and elsewhere, but haven't found an answer so far.

This is how my PHP code looks like for creating the database.

```
function create_DB()
   {
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "");

   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE testbase_db";

   if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
      {
      echo "Database created succesfully";
      }
   else
      {
      echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the database [server/host](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect) on the machine, not a file.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "");
```

Comment: Yes, I know. It was because of trying another suggestion. The above code is now edited to current state.

Comment: @Mr.Asker, so what errors are you getting from your code, based on the error messaging you are trying to display?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem myself. Thanks for all the answers. This question can be removed.